# Could not load type 'umbraco.UmbracoDefault'

Tags: asp.net, .net, umbraco

I have a remote server, in which I accidentally deleted a folder containing the entire website. No biggie, I thought, I just re-created it from the bin, and no damage was seemingly done.

But now the website will not work, due to the following error:

> SERVER ERROR IN '/' APPLICATION
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'umbraco.UmbracoDefault'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 1:  <%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="default.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="umbraco.UmbracoDefault" trace="true" validateRequest="false" %>
> Line 2:
> ```

This is quite serious and I'm now completely out of ideas on what to do!

Comment: That'll teach you to configure and test backups. ;) What do you mean by _"re-created it from the bin"_? Can you get it to run locally? Are all umbraco assemblies copied to the bin folder?

Comment: @SoumyaR please stop suggesting edits with **random bold** and `inline code`. That doesn't improve readability.

Comment: @CodeCaster I was also confused at first, until I remembered that the "recycle bin" deleted files go to is also a bin :P

Comment: You could easy kept a zip of your site.

Comment: As told, it was an accident, however, i do have a backup, yet even with the backup in place (in the same folder, totally replacing the old "broken" one), the same message still pops up, and with no reason :/ As far as i am concerned, EVERY file is still there, and it is EXACTLY how it used to be, before it got randomly deleted, yet for whatever reason, it just won't work :/

Comment: [Enable Fusion Logging](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) to see where it tries to load the assembly and why it fails.

Comment: Thanks for all the input, but so far none have seemingly worked :/ I decided to go back in the server backup and get a few day's old folder, put that in place, and now it works flawlessly... HOWEVER, i still have no idea why a temporarely moved folder, COMPLETELY IDENTICAL to the one i just got from backup, DOESN'T WORK, when the one from backup DOES work.. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: looks like a corrupted umbraco.dll to me.

Answer (score 0):

Recycling the App Pool resolved this for me.